# Resizing all files in a directory using Gifsicle

Tags: bash, gifsicle

I am trying to resize all files in a directory with `Gifsicle` in `MacOs`. I am able to resize single file. But how to resize all files in a directory?

```
gifsicle original.gif --resize 600x600 > _resized.gif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in BASH buddy.

```
#!/bin/bash
my_path=/var/www/mywebpage/images
all_files=$( find $my_path -type f -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.jpeg' -o -name '*.png' -o -name '*.gif' )
cd $my_path;
while read line
do
    echo "About to convert $line ..."
    gifsicle $line --resize 600x600 > ./tmp_image && cat ./tmp_image > $line
    echo "Done!"
done <<< "$all_files"
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
for g in *.gif; do
    d=${g%.gif}; gifsicle --resize 600x600 < "$g" > "$d-resized.gif";
done
```